# How to send a WM_CHAR Message to Firefox

Tags: c++, api

I am trying to send a message of WM_CHAR from an out of process application. I've got the handle to the Firefox window. The FF web page is setup to Yahoo Mail and I would like to populate the user name and password via SendMessage or PostMessage. Does FF process WM_CHAR messages and if not what would be other means of accomplishing the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem you will have is that the widgets are not windowed controls but Firefox XUL components. There are ways to automate it but they involve learning Firefox programming. I'd be astounded if poking text into the Yahoo webmail logon page was the best solution for any problem. Instead of telling what you think the solution is, why don't you tell us the real problem?

Comment: @David Heffernan, good advice. Reminds me of the [5 whys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5_Whys). "Why are you trying to get FF to process WM_CHAR?" "Why are you using SendMessage/PostMessage?" "Why are you trying to login to Yahoo Mail?" etc.

Answer (score 0):

> Does FF process WM_CHAR messages

Visual Studio comes with Spy++ application (\Common7\Tools\spyxx.exe) which you can use to check process messages. If you send or post a message from your process, you can use this utility to watch target process and make sure that the message is actually dispatched.

This is the first step for you to do, and if the message is dispatched and you don't achieve desired behavior, then you might be probably posting a wrong message there...

Comment: FF doesn't use windowed controls so I don't think this will lead anywhere.

Comment: Correct, but it might still be getting keyboard input from messages, such as top level window receives the message and then internally routes then to a windowless control.

Comment: Hello all.

Thanks for all the replies. There is actually no reason for my interest in trying to automate the process of populating the user name and password. Its just for fun exercise no more then that. 

Roman thanks for the tip. I did check Spy++ in Visual Studios 6.0 but found that the WM_CHAR is being sent however there was two entries created in SPY++. I also tried using the On Screen Keyboard which comes with XP. When using the OSK with any window or IE or FF SPY++ does not show any WM_CHAR at all ? Would anyone know why is that ? Thanks again to all for the help.

Comment: Ok everyone I have good news...I was able to populate both the user name and password using keybd_event. Its working fine for Firefox. However I would still like to see if SendMessage will work also. I just want to learn something new...Thanks for the replies everyone.

Comment: I am reporting a weird behavior... I was able to ''SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CHAR, 'a', 0x1);'' a WM_CHAR message to firefox, and in particular to both the search text field in the right top, and a textfield part of a webpage.